# This generic return value is not working

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to return a generic ArrayList from a generic function in which i am passing a class instance but i am getting errors in type cast with the return value

below is the code:

```
public <T extends DefaultHandler> List<M> getItems(Class<T> handlerClass) throws Exception{
    SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
    DefaultHandler handler = null;
    handler=handlerClass.newInstance();
    saxParser.parse("https://www.scoopwhoop.com/rss/category/news", handler);
    return handler.getRSSItemList();  // errorLine 
}
```

The errorline says **since handler is of type DefaultHandler , it can't call the getRSSItemList() function which is in child classes of DefaultHandler**

How can call this method ?

The hierarchy is like this :

```
Class RSSHandler1 extends DefaultHandler
{
  public List<RssItem1> getRSSItemList(){
    return rssItemList;
  }
}

Class RSSHandler2 extends DefaultHandler
{
   public List<RssItem2> getRSSItemList(){
    return rssItemList;
   }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: getRSSItemList() method you are saying ?

Comment: yes, sorry for typo

Comment: if you know for sure it is an rsshandler, why don't you have a superclass for rsshandlers and take rsshandlers as parameters? The code as is makes no sense, you want to call a method on a instance of a type that simply doesn't have the method. This seems entirely unrelated to generics.

Comment: I agree, this code is utterly confusing. Where is that generic M coming from for example. Step back, and create a **real** [mcve] please.

Comment: got your point , let me change the code ..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your generic method accepts any class that is or extends DefaultHandler. There is thus no guarantee that there is a method getRSSItemList in the class. Just because you have two classes that extend DefaultHandler and define such methods isn't sufficient for the compiler.

So you need to pass a class that does have such a method:

```
public interface RSSLister<I> {
    List<I> getRSSItemList();
}

class RSSHandler1 extends DefaultHandler implements RSSLister<RssItem1> {
    public List<RssItem1> getRSSItemList(){
        return rssItemList;
    }
}
```

And your method should be

```
public <I, T extends DefaultHandler & RSSLister<I>> List<I> getItems(Class<T> handlerClass) throws Exception {
    SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
    T handler = handlerClass.newInstance();
    saxParser.parse("https://www.scoopwhoop.com/rss/category/news", handler);
    return handler.getRSSItemList();
}
```

Comment: it works like a charm , now i need to understand it :)

Comment: Worth mentioning this retinaburning signature is trivially avoidable by simply separating the instantiation of the handler and the retrieval of items from it.

Comment: @pvg i didn't get you completely

Comment: @Amol this method does two unrelated things - instantiating a new handler and getting stuff from a handler. Split them up and and you don't need this nightmare of a generic signature. In fact, the whole thing doesn't look like it needs generics at all, you just need some common ancestor or RSSHandler and RSSItem. The whole thing is about 17 times more complicated than it needs to be for no obvious return.

Comment: yes this is complicated , but we can't make common ancestor for RSSItem since List<child> is not subtype of List<Parent>  and i maybe be completely wrong here

Answer (score -1):

Try to cast `handler` to `T` (i.e. `return ((T)handler).getRSSItemList();`)

Comment: He actually needs a List of M in the first place.